# Python application doesn't release file handler quickly

Tags: python-3.x, centos7

```
def write_data_to_disk(file_list):
    for file_name in file_list: # size of file_list is around 20K
        with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
            f.write(...)
            ...
```

The application has a function named as `write_data_to_disk` which takes a list of file names as input and write some incremental data into each file. This function will be repeatedly called by the application.

If I run multiple instances of this application each given unique list of file names, the system will run into problems. Based on my initial investigation, it seems like all launched applications use up all available file handler in the OS and causes other running process to fail. As you can see, within each individual application, it only opens one file to write and then immediately close it and prepare for next writing. Based on my testing results, I will run into problems if I simultaneously run six or eight instances of this application. Does anyone have similar experience before and what is the proper solution to fix the issue?

Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing that it takes some time for Python to write, flush and sync the file buffer during which time the file handle stays, technically, open. Have you tried explicitly syncing and manually closing your handles before moving to the next in line?

Comment: I assume the Python will explicitly close the file handler after I exit the `with` statement. When I move to write next file, the first file should have been closed by Python because the statement is already outside of the `with` scope.

Comment: It will from the user's perspective, but the underlying open file handle (system level) might stay a bit longer until it finishes syncing with the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I mean under explicitly controlling the file handles:

```
import os

def write_data_to_disk(file_list):
    for file_name in file_list:
        with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
            f.write(...)
            f.flush()  # force the buffer flush
            os.fsync(f.fileno())  # force the OS buffer sync (disk write in most cases)
            # let __exit__() close the handler; an explicit f.close() might be faster, tho
```

If that doesn't release your handles faster you'll have to fully delve into [**File Descriptor Operations**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#file-descriptor-operations) and control the whole process instead of letting Python do it for you in the background.

Comment: I thought you wanted me to try the following code instead `f = open(..); f.write(...); f.close(..)`. Thank you for the post, I will give a try.